# Translate det. Turingmachine into formula

Tags: turing-machines, nondeterminism

in the cook-levin theorem a nondet. Turingmachine is translated into a formula of the form:

$\phi$ = $\phi$$_{1}$ $\land$ $\phi$$_{2}$ $\land$ $\phi$$_{3}$ $\land$ $\phi$$_{4}$. I want to know what difference in the formula there is if i would do the same for a DET. Turingmachine and why these differences may occure. Thanks in advance

Comment: A determistic Turing machine is also a nondeterministic Turing machine. Therefore the same formula construction applies.

Comment: Same technique. Only if one want to transform in the 3SAT normal form, the nondeterministic case is slightly more complicated to handle. Actually, if I am not mistaken, the original Cook-proof did not consider nondeterminism: "where $G_{ij}^t$ asserts that is at time $t$ the machine is in state $q_i$ scanning symbol $\sigma_j$, then at time $t+1$ the machine the machine is in state $q_k$, where $q_k$ is the state given by the transition function for $M$." "$G_{ij}^t = \bigwedge_{s=1}^T (\lnot Q_t^i \lor \lnot S_{st} \lor \lnot P_{st}^j \lor \lnot Q_{t+1}^k )$"

Comment: @HendrikJan if the problem is: given a language L through a deterministic turing machine, is the word w in the language L? how would i translate that into a formula(sat/cnf-sat/2-sat)?

Comment: It seems you have to use the recipe for the Cook-Levin construction. That result however assumes polynomial time acceptance, so the number of variables used is polynomially bounded.